# Rewriting Arbitrary Double in QuickCheck2

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

Sorry for a newbie question, but how can I redefine `Arbitrary Double` to produce +/- infinity and NaNs as well as usual doubles? And how to use my version of this `Arbitrary`?

Comment: I see two ways to do this: You can define a `newtype` over `Double` and write a custom `Arbitrary` instance for that. Or you can explicitly pass a `Gen Double` to your test function(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make a new `Arbitrary` instance just to make a custom `Gen`erator for a type. You can just create it as a free-standing definition:

```
evilDouble :: Gen Double
evilDouble = oneOf [ weirdDouble, arbitrary ]
  where
    weirdDouble = error "This is where you generate inf and NaN values"
```

and then use it explicitly with QuickCheck's `forAll`:

```
prop_foo = forAll evilDouble $ \x -> abs (foo x - 123) < 0.1
```

Comment: Here's a hacky implementation I wrote: https://github.com/nick8325/quickcheck/issues/98#issuecomment-722616360